# directional derivative along geodesic flow of vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesics, flows

A rather elementary question for the differential geometers. Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, let $X\colon M \to TM$ be a vector field, and let $$\phi_t = \exp(tX)$$ be the "geodesic flow" of the vector field $X$, that is $\phi_t(p) = \exp_p(t X(p))$ for $p \in M$. I cannot seem to find anything about this notion of flow, does it perhaps have a name I am unaware of?

I am interested in the directional derivative along the flow, that is $$\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \phi_t)(p) = \nabla_{\dot{\phi}_t(p)} f(\phi_t(p))$$ for fixed $p$ and varying $t$. I would hope that, because $\dot{\phi}_t(p)$ is the parallel transport of $X(p)$ along the geodesic $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, $\dot{\gamma}(0) = X(p)$, there might be an expression involving only $X$ and the map $\phi_t$.

**Edit:**

I think the question might be whether one can use the fact that $\phi_t$ is actually a map on $M$. The directional derivative is e.g. in terms of the exterior derivative$$\nabla_{\dot{\phi}_t(p)} f(\phi_t(p)) = df_{\phi_t(p)}(\dot{\phi}_t(p)).$$
If, instead of the parallel transport $\dot{\phi}_t(p)$, we had the pushforward $d\phi_t X$ of $X$ by $\phi_t$, then this would simply be the pullback
$$df_{\phi_t(p)}(d\phi_t X) = d(\phi_t^*f)_p(X) = X(\phi_t^*f)_p.$$
So I guess this boils down to a question about the difference between the pushforward of the exponential map and parallel transport, which should be a property of the (smoothness?) of the vector field $X$. Is there a way to make this idea more precise?

Comment: If you understand the tangent space as set of point derivations, then the directional derivative is the vector field itself.

Comment: Since you’re fixing $p$, doesn’t your expression depend only on $X(p)$? I don’t see any alternative to saying it’s the directional derivative in the direction of the parallel translate of $X$.

Comment: @DeaneYang Well, you are right of course that there is nothing deep about the problem. I am merely curious if there is a straightforward way to bring the computation back to $t = 0$, if you will, and to understand when that can or cannot be done. My particular reason is that I have $X$ and $f \circ \phi_t$ readily available, but cannot easily evaluate the parallel transport.

Comment: In that case there’s no need to define $X$ as a vector field. You’re looking simply at the geodesic starting at a point $p$ with initial velocity X(p). Since the parallel transport depends on the geometry of the space along the geodesic and not just at $p$, I don’t see how to write the directional derivative using only data at $p$.

Comment: @DeaneYang I agree, and perhaps it is naive to expect that anything can be said at all. But I am still thinking that _something_ must be known about the derivative from the structure of the maps: Looking at e.g. [this somewhat related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126104/difference-between-parallel-transport-and-derivative-of-the-exponential-map) I take it that the difference between $\dot{\phi}_t(p)$ and $d\phi_t X$ is second order in $tX$ -- that would be a start.

Comment: @user144437, the post you refer to is about the differential of the exponential map and how it's related to Jacobi fields along each geodesic. Jacobi fields are defined using parallel translation. So the discussion there doesn't add any more insight.